# Unable to form the MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a table called TblNodeModHistory it store the allrecord of users who modified the note.

Let say for a particular node called 33856 which is modified by in this manner user A then user B,then user again User B ,then user C,then user B,user A and so on.Now I want to list last 10 records with the previous record so the output of the query will be A,B,C,B,A like this. If any user modified simultaneously then only last modification information will be taken.

I have written the given query:

```
$sql_history = "select FldChangedBy,FldLastChangedOn,FldDeletedOrEdited 
                from TblNodeModHistory 
                where FldNodeId ='".$PrNodeId."' 
                group by FldChangedBy 
                ORDER BY FldLastChangedOn DESC";
```

but I didn't get the desired result. How can I construct the query?

Comment: My DBA always tells me to try it from the database client (`mysql` in your case) whenever I approach him with such issues.  Also you don't seem to accept answers so you won't get many.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. You don't need the group by though as you're not doing any group functions like sum or count etc. Also you mentioned you need the last 10 items so get these through LIMIT 10

```
select 
  FldChangedBy
  ,FldLastChangedOn
  ,FldDeletedOrEdited 
from TblNodeModHistory                 
where FldNodeId ='".$PrNodeId."' 
order by FldLastChangedOn DESC
limit 10
```

Comment: :- Sorry to said that u didn't understand my requirement but thanks for ur suggession.. :-)